# JavaScript shorthand ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I know that in PHP 5.3 instead of using this redundant ternary operator syntax:

```
startingNum = startingNum ? startingNum : 1
```

...we can use a shorthand syntax for our ternary operators where applicable:

```
startingNum = startingNum ?: 1
```

And I know about the ternary operator in JavaScript:

```
startingNum = startingNum ? startingNum : 1
```

...but is there a shorthand?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
var startingNumber = startingNumber || 1;
```

Something like that what you're looking for, where it defaults if undefined?

```
var foo = bar || 1; // 1
var bar = 2;
foo = bar || 1;     // 2
```

By the way, this works for a lot of scenarios, including objects:

```
var foo = bar || {}; // secure an object is assigned when bar is absent
```

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it. I'm actually using an object in this instance. :)

Comment: For anyone curious, this works because JS's `||` operator doesn't return true or false, it returns the first 'truthy' value.  Say you have `val0` and `val1` as `undefined`, and `val2` is `2`, `val3` is `3`.  `val0 || val1 || val2 || val3` will return `2`, as it is the first 'truthy' value.

Comment: Isn't this idiom an anti-pattern? What if you pass 0 or empty string, the 'OR' expression will skip it and use the default value where you actually wanted 0 or empty string.

Comment: @Paul indeed, it's a coalesce operation, but mimics what OP requested. The behavior is no different than OP's example.

Comment: These comments would be great added to the answer too for some context on what it is called "coalesce operation" and how it works :)

Answer (score 37):

`||` will return the first truthy value it encounters, and can therefore be used as a coalescing operator, similar to C#'s `??`

```
startingNum = startingNum || 1;
```

Comment: I like your explanation more than the other ones

Comment: Worth nothing it also returns the last value if none are truthy, which is handy for falling back to a known type, e.g. `stringOrUndefinedVar || ''`.

Answer (score 18):

With the addition of ES2020:

**New** w/Nullish Coalescence: `const difficulty = var?.nest[i]?.prop ?? false`

Older Operation: `const difficulty = var.nest[i].prop ? var.nest[i].prop : false`

The question mark before the property will first check if the object even exists (if you aren't sure it will: like in API data) and, if an object is missing, it will return `undefined`

The `??` checks if the value on the left is `null` or `undefined` and, if it is, will return a supplied value on the right.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is:

```
var startingNum = startingNum || 1;
```

In general, `expr1 || expr2` works in the following way (as mentioned by [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)):

> **Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.** Thus, when used with `Boolean` values, `||` returns `true` if either operand is `true`; if both are `false`, returns `false`.

Comment: Isn't it more correct to say `if a is truthy` vs. `if a is evaluated to true`?

Comment: @JaredPar: To avoid ambiguity, I have replaced my original detailed explanation with the one from Mozilla Developer Network. It should be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 8):

In most modern browsers you can now use:

```
startingNum ??= 1;
```

This will only change `startingNum` if it is `null` or `undefined`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 3):

```
startingNum = startingNum || 1
```

If you have a condition with null, like

```
startingNum = startingNum ? startingNum : null
```

you can use '&&'

```
startingNum = startingNum && startingNum
```

Comment: But won't `anything && null` evaluate to null unless `anything` is falsy?

Comment: Yeah, if anything is truthy it evaluates to null. If its falsy, evaluates to the falsy value

Answer (score 3):

To make a ternary like:

```
boolean_condition ? true_result : false_result
```

in javascript, you can do:

```
(boolean_condition && true_result ) || false_result;
```

Example:

```
(true && 'green') || 'red';
=> "green"
(false && 'green') || 'red';
=> "red"
```

Comment: sooo `x = innerWidth * 0.0375 > 24 ? innerWidth * 0.0375 : 24` would become `(innerWidth * 0.0375 > 24 && innerWidth * 0.0375) || 24`?? is there a shorthand, so that i dont have to repeat `innerWidth * 0.0375`, other than assigning it to a variable???

Comment: In this case, `Math.max( innerWidth * 0.0375 , 24 )` would work elegantly. For a more general case, it would be good to create a descriptive method called e.g.  'somethingifiedInnerWidth' which improves readability, rather than create a variable. Though in some cases it would be more readable to have a variable (of that descriptive name), so in future the question 'why is it multiplied by this?' is not raised.

Comment: wow didnt even know u could provide a 2nd argument for `Math.max`. super elegant solution!!

Comment: I needed the `boolean_condition`, so this I need for the ternary. But this does not work: `(if coll=='pages' && sort='cat' ) || sort='';` What is wrong?

Comment: @Timo `sort = (coll=='pages' && 'cat') || ''` should work. If for some reason you needed those inline assignments you could do `(coll=='pages' && (sort='cat')) || (sort='')`

Answer (score 2):

```
var startingNum = startingNum || 1;
```

In this case, you can use the OR operator.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct. In JavaScript, the following statement:

```
startingNum = startingNum ? otherNum : 1
```

can be expressed as

```
startingNum = otherNum || 1
```

Another scenario not covered here is if you want the value to return false when not matched. The JavaScript shorthand for this is:

```
startingNum = startingNum ? otherNum : 0
```

But it can be expressed as

```
startingNum = startingNum && otherNum
```

Just wanted to cover another scenario in case others were looking for a more generalized answer.

Comment: is there a shorthand for something like this: `x = innerWidth * 0.0375 > 24 ? innerWidth * 0.0375 : 24` ???

Comment: @Anthony No, because `innerWidth * 0.0375 > 24` differs from the `if true` part which is `innerWidth * 0.0375`. The shorthand can only be used if the `expression to be evaluated` and the `if true` are the same value. Same why you wouldn't be able to shorthand `x = someBoolean ? 'Heck yea!' : 'No way!'`.

Comment: @deedub well, actually, there is a "shorthand" (if youd call it that) which would be `Math.max(innerWidth * 0.0375, 24)`

Comment: @Anthony You wouldn't call it that ;) But `Math.max` works better than a ternary operator in your use case.

Comment: "`startingNum = startingNum ? otherNum : 1` can be expressed as `startingNum = otherNum || 1`" is wrong. i just tested this

Comment: @Anthony [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22870338) has been rejected because you're not supposed to use edits to change the intent of posts. If you disagree, you should downvote, comment (you did that already), or post an opposing answer. But you shouldn't remove parts of other answers because they're wrong or you disagree with them.

Comment: @WaiHaLee lol i didnt remove it cuz i disagree with it. its *literally* wrong aka ***code that does not work the way he claims it does.*** hes claimed that `startingNum = startingNum ? otherNum : 1` is equivalent to `startingNum = otherNum || 1`, which may be true for numbers and in some other cases, but false in the explicit context of the question, which was "is there a shorthand for the ternary operator". youre going to have new programmers possibly stumbling upon this Q and likely becoming completely misinformed and oblivious to the fact.

Comment: @Anthony so you're saying it's wrong? Then downvote or post an opposing answer and let the community decide. You've already commented, and the answer has one downvote (I won't ask if it's yours). Anything further isn't appropriate. Just as I'm at liberty to post an answer claiming that "the ternary operator swaps the left and right operands and prints them to the screen" this answer can be wrong. If you disagree I'd suggest you create a question on Meta (comment here and I'll post a reply).

Comment: @WaiHaLee it is my down vote. i mean, if this community exists to help ppl learn and improve their programming, personally i think something should be done about it, but i guess thats not what the community stands for? lol

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to be correct? `startingNum = startingNum ? otherNum : 1` assigns a value to startingNum based on the truthyness of startingNum (regardless of the truthyness of otherNum), if startingNum is falsy, you get 1, otherwise you get otherNum. Additionally this wouldn't work if startingNum is a const. `startingNum = otherNum || 1` on the other hand assigns a value to startingNum based on the truthyness of otherNum, if otherNum is falsy you get 1, otherwise you get otherNum.

Answer (score 1):

Re @Joshu's 'nullish' answer.

The shortcut, or Optional Chaining operator, "?." keeps the dot when used prior to a square bracket for a string (unknown) property, instead of a known property, eg.:

```
object.propLevel1?.[unknownPropLevel2]
```

At first usage, for me, it seemed appropriate to drop the dot:

```
object.propLevel1?[unknownPropLevel2] // WRONG
```

From mdn: Syntax

```
obj.val?.prop
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.func?.(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accepted answer, but it's not ideal as it breaks when used with bools, if you're defaulting to true, it will always evaluate to true ->

```
var undefinedVal: boolean;
var trueVal = true;
var falseVal = false;
```

Angular Template ex:

```
Value : {{ undefinedVal || true }} -> true
Value : {{ trueVal || true }} -> true
Value : {{ falseVal || true }} -> true?
```

So use the long way when using bools:

```
Value : {{ (val != null) ? val : true }}
```

Also note for typescript and C# (I think), when using ternary with string concatenation it has to be in brackets ->

```
console.log("Value :" + ((val != null) ? val : true));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var startingNum = startingNum || 1;
```

Can (in this case) be shortened to:

```js
var startingNum =|| 1;
```

See *[Logical OR assignment (**`||=`**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)*.

See also *[Nullish coalescing assignment (**`??=`**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)*.