# Javascript set undefined value to a default value, but only if undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I would like to know if this is the best way to approach this javascript problem. I would like to first detect if a variable is undefined. If it is not, I would like to insert a default value.

Example, This if statement is receiving a variable called zoomControl.  It can have 3 possible values.  true, false, or undefined.

I would like the output to be: true = true, false = false, undefined = true

```
if (opt.set_zoomControl) {
            set_zoomControl = opt.set_zoomControl
    } else {
        set_zoomControl = true;
    }
```

Is this efficient?  Can this be shorted or rewritten?

thank you.

Comment: this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884071/javascript-shorthand-ternary-operator  set_zoomControl = opt.set_zoomControl  || true;

Answer (score 1):

```
set_zoomControl = ( opt.set_zoomControl === false )? false: true;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot a key requirement in my question description.  The default value (undefined value) is not always true.  (As in the example code).  The default value maybe sometimes be false. This works for both occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (opt.set_zoomControl) {
            //true
}
else{
       //false or undefinded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most concise way to write this:

```
set_zoomControl = opt.set_zoomControl !== false;
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to see that this works for all three of your cases:

```
false !== false      // evaluates to false
true !== false       // evaluates to true
undefined !== false  // evaluates to true
```

Your current method will result in `set_zoomControl` always being `true`.  If you wanted to use your if/else format for clarity it will be most straightforward to handle the false case first and then let true and undefined be handled by the `else`:

```
if (opt.set_zoomControl === false) {
    set_zoomControl = false;
} else {
    set_zoomControl = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_zoomControl = opt.set_zoomControl || 0;`