# JSON recursive value substitution against another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json object which consist of arrays, and maps with some placeholder text that can be substituted by passing another object.

Eg.

```
data = {
  "name": "Hello ${user.name}",  
  "primary_task": "Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name}",
  "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]
}
```

Variables or metadata object can be

```
variables = {
  "user": {
    "name": "DJ"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task One"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a function that can take the string and subtitute based on some object. I am not sure how to invoke this on a JSON object recursively so that it can substitute all the string values in map and array

```
var data = {
  "name": "Hello ${user.name}",  
  "primary_task": "Task Name: Task One",
  "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]
}

var metadata = {
  "user": {
    "name": "DJ",
    "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Task One"
    }
  ],
  },  
}

function subString(str) {
  var rxp = /\{([^}]+)\}/g,    
    liveStr = str,
    curMatch;

while( curMatch = rxp.exec( str ) ) {
    var match = curMatch[1];
    liveStr = liveStr.replace("${"+ match + "}", tryEval(match));    
}
return liveStr;
}


function tryEval(evalStr) {
  evalStr = "metadata." + evalStr;
  try {
  return eval(evalStr);
}
catch(error) {
  return "${" + evalStr + "}";
}

}
var str = "user ${user.name} - ${user.tasks[0].name} - ${user.tasks[2].name}";

console.log("Sub " + subString(str));
```

In the above example, `${user.tasks[2].name}` **does not exist** in meta so **it should not resolve to undefined**. If the key is not found in meta object, it should leave that as is i.e. `${user.tasks[2].name}`

Comment: I wrote a resolve property function, you could extend it to also work with arrays. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fchtqv

Comment: Why was the app designed like this in 1st place?

Comment: Where does data and metadata come from? How do the ${} bits get into the data? I assume you are not hard coding the data? Are there any parameters defining structure of metadata? What if data has a field metadata does not?

Comment: The `metadata.user.tasks` has only one item in it, which is why `"Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"` isn't being replaced (`user.tasks[2]` doesn't exist). What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **ES6** only scenario:

```js
const data = { "name": "Hello ${user.name} ${user.foo}", "primary_task": "Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name} ${user.tasks[10].name}", "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[0].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 3: ${user.tasks[11].name}"] }
const meta = { "user": { "name": "DJ", "tasks": [ { "name": "Task One" }, { "name": "Task Two" } ] } }

const getPath = (path, obj) => path.split('.').reduce((r, c) =>
  r ? c.includes('[') ? getPath(c.replace('[', '.').replace(']', ''), r) : r[c] : undefined, obj)

const interpolate = (s, v) =>
  new Function(...Object.keys(v), `return \`${s}\`;`)(...Object.values(v))

const templ = (str, obj) => {
  let r = new RegExp(/\${([\s\S]+?)}/g)
  while (match = r.exec(str)) {
    if (!getPath(match[1], obj))
      str = str.replace(match[0], match[0].replace('${', '__'))
  }
  return interpolate(str, obj).replace('__', '${')
}

const resolve = (d, vars) => {
  if (Array.isArray(d))
    return d.map(x => templ(x, vars))
  else
    return Object.entries(d).reduce((r, [k, v]) =>
      (r[k] = Array.isArray(v) ? resolve(v, vars) : templ(v, vars), r), {})
}

console.log(resolve(data, meta))
```

The string interpolation idea was influenced by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884071/javascript-shorthand-ternary-operator). The idea 
is to traverse all object values recursively and use the `interpolate` function to return the actual hydrated strings. To traverse the paths `getPath` is used as well as to spot non existing paths. If a path in a string does not exists string replacement is used to get that string pass the string hydration and after that we replace back.

**Lodash _.template** scenario:

In a scenario where you can utilize `lodash` and its [**templating mechanism**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#template) (via `_.template`) then this becomes even simpler problem to solve since we already have the interpolation function:

```js
const data = { "name": "Hello ${user.name} ${user.foo}", "primary_task": "Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name} ${user.tasks[10].name}", "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[0].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 3: ${user.tasks[11].name}"] }
const meta = { "user": { "name": "DJ", "tasks": [ { "name": "Task One" }, { "name": "Task Two" } ] } }

const templ = (str, obj) => {
  let r = new RegExp(/\${([\s\S]+?)}/g)
  while (match = r.exec(str)) {
    if (!_.get(obj, match[1]))
      str = str.replace(match[0], match[0].replace('${', '__'))
  }
  return _.template(str)(obj).replace('__', '${')
}

const resolve = (d, vars) => {
  if (_.isArray(d))
    return _.map(d, x => templ(x, vars))
  else
    return _.entries(d).reduce((r, [k, v]) =>
      (r[k] = _.isArray(v) ? resolve(v, vars) : templ(v, vars), r), {})
}

console.log(resolve(data, meta))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is recursively to walk the object tree and convert any simple properties to strings via the lodash `_.template`. Use `Array.map` or `_.map` to go through the arrays and `Array.reduce` or `_.reduce` to go through the objects in order to convert them to the template strings.

The only problem is the requirement to leave `paths` which do not exists. To get that working we check which path does not exists replace its `${` with `__` and when the `_.template` function is done with the hydrating the string we replace it back.

Comment: i like your solution but if the key doesn't exist in meta object, it will resolve to undefined. For eg: if user.tasks[1].name doesn't exist in meta object, it should leave it as that instead of setting as undefined.

Comment: @ed1t both solutions updated to support your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using the [loadash](https://lodash.com/) utility library:

```
var _ = require('lodash'); // use for node
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>; // use for browser
```

---

```js
var data = {
"name": "Hello ${user.name}",
"primary_task": "Task Name: Task One",
"secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[0].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}"]
}

var metadata = {
"user": {
    "name": "DJ",
    "tasks": [{
            "name": "Task One"
        },
        {
            "name": "Task Two"
        }
    ],
},
}
var text = JSON.stringify(data); // stringify data object
var myregexp = /\${([\[\]a-z\d.]+)}/i // regex to match the content to be replaced in data
while (match = myregexp.exec(text)) { // loop all matches
try {
    // Example: [0]=${user.name} / [1]=user.name
    new_data = text.replace(match[0], _.get(metadata, match[1])); // replace values using _ library
    text = new_data;
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Requested element doesn't exist", err.message);
}
match = myregexp.exec(text);
}
var new_data = JSON.parse(new_data); // convert new_data to object
console.log(new_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Notes:

1. [Codepen.io Demo](https://codepen.io/tuga/pen/pQeOxq)
2. [Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)

Comment: why using `eval`? It is NOT needed and potentialy harmfull

Comment: As stated in the commented code, I couldn't find a  better solution for this problem. If you have an alternative to `eval`, feel free to show it.

Comment: sure you can traverse the metadata struct based on the matched key. The matched key is  either object-based ie `param`.param2` (split on `.`) and/or array-based ie `param1[index2]` where you split on `[]` and match the index. It is more work than eval but definately better to use

Comment: I'm not a js expert myself and struggled with the array based items, other values are easy to implement without `eval`, i.e.: `[metadata][user.name]`

Comment: first you transform the array-based indexes to object-based usign a regex like `matchKey.replace(/\[([^\[\]])\]/, ".$1");` then trim leading/trailing dots `matchedKey = matchKey.replace(/^\.|\.$/, "");` then uyou split on dots and traverse the metadata struct based on each sub-key, if no key exists then return an error else return the final value. This should work

Comment: I've found a good alternative to `eval`, the [`_lodash`](https://lodash.com/) library, which is perfect for this case -  .Answer updated, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: that lodash function implements what I have described in my comment, but better yet isolate the code from lodash and use it as an autonomus function to avoid including 3rd-pary libraries only for a function

Comment: If the key doesn't exist in meta object, it will resolve to undefined. For eg: if user.tasks[1].name doesn't exist in meta object, it should leave it as that instead of setting as undefined. My original function left it as ${user.tasks[1].name}

Comment: @ed1t That's easy to fix, I'll do it asa I'm on pc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with pure JS by simply using JSON.stringify, regex, [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match),  [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and some other methods.

Something that did cause issues, is that your "variables" variable doesn't seem to have the correct format. "tasks" should be a child of "user". I've fixed that for you if that is indeed what you intended.

*This is definitely optimizable so let me know if there is anything to simplify.*

### Solution:

```js
data = {
  "name": "Hello ${user.name}",
  "primary_task": "Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name}",
  "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]
}

variables = {
  "user": {
    "name": "DJ",
    "tasks": [{
        "name": "Task Primary"
      },
      {
        "name": "Task One"
      },
      {
        "name": "Task Two"
      }
    ]
  }
}

const str = JSON.stringify(data);
const reg = /\$\{([a-z]|\[\d\]|\.)+\}/gi

const res = str.match(reg).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  //slice to remove ${ and }
  const val = cur.slice(2, -1).split(".").reduce((acc2, cur2) => {
    //check to see if it's like for example: tasks[1]
    if (cur2.indexOf("[") > -1) {
      const s = cur2.split("[");
      //Ex: acc2["tasks"][0]
      //slice to remove trailing "]"
      return acc2[s[0]][s[1].slice(0,-1)];
    }
    //Ex acc2["user"]
    return acc2[cur2];
  }, variables);
  //val contains the value used to replace the variable string name
  return acc.replace(cur, val);
}, str);

console.log(JSON.parse(res))
```

### The logic behind how this was made was the following:

Get all str variable names in an array and later loop through it with reduce

```js
const str = '{"name":"Hello ${user.name}","primary_task":"Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name}","secondary_tasks":["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}","Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]}'

console.log(str.match(/\$\{([a-z]|\[\d\]|\.)+\}/gi))
```

For each value in the str.match() array find the corresponding value

```js
const arrayOfStringProperties = "${user.tasks[2].name}".slice(2,-1).split(".")

console.log(arrayOfStringProperties);

//tasks[2] is the one a bit more complicated to handle

const task = "tasks[2]".split("[");
console.log(task[0], task[1].slice(0,-1));

//this allows us to get the value: metadata["user"]["tasks"]["2"]
variables = {"user": {"name": "DJ","tasks": [{"name": "Task Primary"},{"name": "Task One"},{"name": "Task Two"}]}}

console.log(variables["user"]["tasks"]["2"]["name"]);
```

### Error handling and async:

Here is the solution wrapped in an async function to eventually catch any errors.

```js
dataNoError = {
  "name": "Hello ${user.name}",
  "primary_task": "Task Name: ${user.tasks[0].name}",
  "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]
}

dataWithError = {
  "name": "Hello ${user.name}",
  "primary_task": "Task Name: ${usera.tasks[0].name}",
  "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[1].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]
}

variables = {
  "user": {
    "name": "DJ",
    "tasks": [{
        "name": "Task Primary"
      },
      {
        "name": "Task One"
      },
      {
        "name": "Task Two"
      }
    ]
  }
}

async function substitution(metadata, data) {
  const str = JSON.stringify(data);
  const reg = /\$\{([a-z]|\[\d\]|\.)+\}/gi

  const res = str.match(reg).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    //slice to remove ${ and }
    const val = cur.slice(2, -1).split(".").reduce((acc2, cur2) => {
      //check to see if it's like for example: tasks[1]
      if (cur2.indexOf("[") > -1) {
        const s = cur2.split("[");
        //Ex: acc2["tasks"][0]
        //slice to remove trailing "]"
        return acc2[s[0]][s[1].slice(0, -1)];
      }
      //Ex acc2["user"]
      return acc2[cur2];
    }, metadata);
    //val contains the value used to replace the variable string name
    return acc.replace(cur, val);
  }, str);

  return JSON.parse(res);
}

substitution(variables, dataNoError).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.warn(err.message));

substitution(variables, dataWithError).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.warn(err.message));
```

Comment: If the key doesn't exist in meta object, it will resolve to undefined. For eg: if user.tasks[1].name doesn't exist in meta object, it should leave it as instead of setting as undefined. My original function left it as ${user.tasks[1].name}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It is basically a function (get) which gets you the value (if any) following the path, and a function (replaceWhereDefined) which given a value, will replace it on your data. Hope this helps.

```js
const data = {"name": "Hello ${user.name}", "primary_task": "Task Name: Task One", "secondary_tasks": ["Task 2: ${user.tasks[0].name}", "Task 2: ${user.tasks[2].name}"]};

const meta = {"user": {"name": "DJ", "tasks": [{"name": "Task One"}] } };

const get = (s, meta) => {

    const parts = s.replace(/(\${)|}/g, '').split('.');

    const value = parts.reduce((acc, val) => {

        const isArray = val.match(/\[\d+]/g);

        if (isArray) {

            const arr = val.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g).toString();

            const position = isArray.toString().replace(/[\[\]]/g, '');

            acc = acc[arr];

            if (acc) acc = acc[position];
        }

        else acc = acc[val];

        return acc || {};

    }, meta);

    return typeof value === 'string' ? value : null;
};

const replaceWhereDefined = (data, meta) =>

    Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {

        const toReplace = data[key].toString().match(/\${.*?}/g);

        if (toReplace) {

            toReplace.forEach((path) => {

                const value = get(path, meta);

                if (Array.isArray(acc[key]) && value) {

                    acc[key] = acc[key].map((d) => d.replace(path, value));
                }

                else if (value) acc[key] = acc[key].replace(path, value);
            });
        }

        return acc;

    }, data);

console.log(replaceWhereDefined(data, meta));
```